# Can we increment each record in a table using one of the records from the last row?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Can we keep incrementing column B using column A in redshift-sql. Example:

> Column A Column B

```
0            0
1            1 (0+1)
2            3 (2+1)
3            6 (3+3)
4            10 (4+6)
5            15 (10+5)
6            21 (15+6)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If memory serves, Amazon-Redshift does have window functions

This was tested in SQL Server

```
Declare @Table table (ColumnA int)
Insert into @Table values 
(0),
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4),
(5),
(6)

Select ColumnA
      ,ColumnB = sum(ColumnA) over (Order by ColumnA)
 From @Table
```

Returns

```
ColumnA ColumnB
0       0
1       1
2       3
3       6
4       10
5       15
6       21
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer